# UITabBarController with 6 real tabs associated with UIViewControllers, but with 5 tab buttons and one tab called only programically

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I have UITabBarController with 6 tabs associated with UIViewControllers, but one of theme I want to call only programically (no item button). So how I can set this UIViewController to be without tab button in the tab bar ? I removed the title text and image but still is set on the bottom bar. Any ideas ?

Comment: The answer depends on how you want to present it -- do you want it to be available from any of the other controllers, or just one? What is the function of this controller? Why don't you want it to have its own tab?

Answer (score 0):

It's my post but from other profile...So the case is that:
I have five tabs. On each tab I have "detail button". When it's clicked from particular tab it's needed to be shown specific information. This detail tab is my six tab (but without tab button on the bottom) because it's called programically